# NSTableView versus Core Animation layers

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` with a scope bar above that I want to animate showing and hiding. I'm doing this by putting them in a stack view using `NSAnimationContext` to animate the height constraint of the scope bar. So far so good.

The problem is that `NSAnimationContext` requires Core Animation layers, and NSTableView interacts badly with them. I've searched and found several complaints about this. It leads to really weird drawing errors that seem to happen when cell views are reused during scrolling. Simply turning layers off in the xib file fixes the drawing errors, but breaks the animation.

I tried going back to the old `NSViewAnimation` approach, but it doesn't work with layout constraints.

So is there a way to either a) make the table view work with layers, or b) animate the scope bar without layers?

Comment: I would use a group row (floating) for my scope bar so i could use the standard table view animations to show and hide the view. Another possibility would be to switch to layers only temporary when the scope bar will animate.

Comment: I've tried setting `view.layer = false` after the animation but the table view remains messed up.

Comment: Interestingly, in the macOS 10.14 beta, without turning any CA layers on, the animation works and the table view is still fine.